# Which Stack Exchange site is best for Microsoft Exchange questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site is best for Microsoft Exchange questions?

It is related to public folders and exporting them out to an SMB file share with a predefined folder hierarchy. A solution could possibly include scripting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @gnat That post definitely does not answer my question

Comment: did you check [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) over there?

Comment: What kind of question about MS Exchange?

Comment: @gnat Yes. I don't see how microsoft exchange falls into any of the categories defined in that answer. My question is very specific. I only want to know where i can ask a microsoft exchange question. i don't see how this can be marked as a duplicate of that question which is very generic

Comment: @Oded It is related to public folders and exporting them out to an smb file share with a predefined folder hierarchy. Thank you!

Comment: So, system administration questions? Or is that more of an end user sort of question? Or does this involve code?

Comment: Yes, true. A solution could possibly include scripts too though

Comment: Thing is - each of these could mean a different site. If this is system administration, [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) is the best bet, even with scripting. If it is an end user question, possibly [Super User](http://superuser.com). If this is primarily a coding question, then [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is your best bet. Really depends on the details of the question...

Comment: @slayer: That's important information that should be in your question, not the comments.

Comment: @Oded I think Server Fault will be ideal. Thanks

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce Added. thanks

Comment: @gnat Searching that other question for "MS Exchange" / "Microsoft Exchange" yields no results at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That depends. If your question is about...

- ...administering an Exchange server in a professional environment, [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) (tagged [`exchange`](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exchange))
- ...connecting to a server or managing it as a hobbyist (e.g., using it at home), [Super User](http://superuser.com) (tagged [`exchange`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/exchange))
- ...writing code to script functionality, probably [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) (tagged [`exchange-server`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exchange-server))

  > Questions about automation and APIs related to Microsoft's Enterprise level messaging server.